# How do I make a form field the same as another field?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a form that allows a user to edit an employee's history with the company.

I want to make it so when the user changed the "To position" dropdown menu of the first entry it changes the "From position" dropdown menu in the next entry to be equal to it.

```
 <% f.fields_for :employee_position_histories do |emp_pos_his| %>
    <table class="crud-form">
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :from_position_id,  " Start Position: " %></td>
        <td><%= f.collection_select :from_position_id, Position.active, :id, :title, { :prompt => ' Select a Position ' }, { :class => 'clean average' } %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>  
        <td><%= f.label :to_position_id,  " To Position: " %></td>
        <td><%= f.collection_select :to_position_id, Position.active, :id, :title, { :prompt => ' Select a Position ' }, { :class => 'clean average' } %></td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :started_at, "Start Date: "%></td>
        <td><%= f.date_picker :started_at, :class => "clean average" %>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :ended_at, "End Date: "%></td>
        <td><%= f.date_picker :ended_at, :class => "clean average" %>
      </tr>
      <hr>
    </table> 
<% end %>
```

I am unsure of the best way to do this. A colleague of mine said to use jscript but I am not sure how to do that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to do this:

```
var fromBox = $("#from");
fromBox.change(function () {
    $("#to").val(fromBox.val());
});
```

just replace the "#to" and "#from" with your ID's

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hummlas/m87ap/

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help. One other question i do have is that this form can have a difference number of entries from employee to employee. Therefore the ids are not static. Here is an example of a from id and a to id. employee_employee_position_histories_attributes_0_to_position_id  
employee_employee_position_histories_attributes_1_from_position_id.                                                                       Is there a way to dynamically change the id names?

Comment: if you know the logic of how the IDs are generated for the dropdowns it shouldn't be a problem to create them dynamically in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with ruby syntax so I can't tell what you use for your select ids.
Here's a way to do it without jQuery:

```
var fromBox = document.getElementById("from");

fromBox.addEventListener('change',function() {
     document.getElementById("to").value = fromBox.value;
}, false);
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h5gew/12/